# What are the connectors for black irrigation hose called?

Tags: plumbing, irrigation

I’m fixing my irrigation and there are some cracks that I need to cut out and reconnect them. I have these connections already but being new to irrigation, I’m not sure what to call them. See the attached images for a zoom in and a zoomed out with red highlight.[image]

[image]

Comment: That's just one random brand of "drip irrigation" tube and fittings. They are NOT "standard" and the fittings and tube are not always interchangeable between different brands (although many manufacturers have wised up and made stuff compatible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home Depot calls them compression couplings. [Here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DIG-1-2-in-0-700-O-D-Compression-Coupling-C33/100112407) is an example.

[image: compression coupling on irrigation hose]

And if you are looking for the type that go on the inside of the hose, it'll be called a barbed coupling or barbed connector.

Answer (score 2):

Thes are also called Push to Connect fittings.

Answer (score 1):

You have standard couplings and t’s.
since it’s above ground I would guess low pressure drip irrigation. There are tons of brands I just make sure the size is correct and go to a big box store. But Amazon also has them some are called compression, some barbed but coupling is for 1 pipe to another and T is for 3 pieces